# jquery replaceWith and bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I am using bootstrap-sass 2.1.1.0 with rails 3.2.9. 
I have a ajax form inside modal. like this:

```
section#avatars_form_edit
  = simple_form_for [user, avatar], html: { class: 'edit-avatar' }, remote: true do |f|
    - %w(x y w h).each do |attribute|
      = f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}"
    a.btn href='#' data-dismiss='modal' = t '.cancel'
    = f.button :submit, value: t('.confirm')
```

After submit successful I would like to hide modal and replace element in the page under the modal: (update.js.erb)

```
<% if @avatar.errors.any? %>
  <% error = @avatar.errors[:image].first %>
  $('#avatars_form').
    find('.modal-body').prepend('<%= j render "shared/embedded_notify", key: "alert", msg: error %>');
<% else %>
  $('#avatars_modal').modal('hide');
  $('#avatars_avatar_medium').
    replaceWith('<%= j render "avatar_medium", avatar: @avatar, user: @user %>');
  $('#avatars_avatar_medium').
    on('hover', function() { $(this).find('.edit-bar').toggleClass('invisible'); });
<% end %>
```

The question is: **Sometimes**(90% times it work), the replaceWith($('#avatars_avatar_medium').
        replaceWith('<%= j render "avatar_medium", avatar: @avatar, user: @user %>');) seems not work. It does not update my page. I am not good at javasript can you tell the problem? Thanks!

Comment: please post the actual browser source code when it fails. Also are any errors thrown?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I find out the reason: **Browser Cache**. It can be solved by generate a unique file name.